# SQL Oracle - checking value in another table with CHECK or TRIGGER

Tags: oracle

Is any way, how to create table with CHECK (or maybe TRIGGER?), that will check, if inserted value is already in another table?

Example

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
  Name VARCHAR(10),
  Adress VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Section(
  Section_name VARCHAR(10),
  Managers_name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

And I want to check, that value inserted to Managers_name is already in Employee, if it isnt, then print error.

I found any ways, how it could be done, but everything I tried in Oracle, didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint to the employee table and a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to the section table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
  Name VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT Employee_Name_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Adress VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Section(
  Section_name  VARCHAR(10),
  Managers_name VARCHAR(10)
                CONSTRAINT section_manager_fk REFERENCES Employee( Name )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is any way how to do it with CHECK or TRIGGER command?

Comment: `CHECK` is a constraint but only references columns in the same table so it won't work and a `TRIGGER` could look and see if the value was not in the table and prevent an insert but you cannot return values from a `TRIGGER` to the user so it would not be able to "print" an output.

Answer (score 0):

Check constraint is, as explained by mt0, devoted to single table.
Trigger is to be avoided for consistency reasons: while you're selecting a record, another session might be in the process of deleting it.

The Foreign Key is the correct way to implement it: Trap FK constraint violation in your code (ORA-02291 i guess), search for "section_manager_fk" in the message and finally rewrite a user-friendly error message.